# Load language file globally in fulephp for multilingual website

Tags: fuelphp

I am new in fuelphp. I want to create multilingual website. I created a dropdown

```
   <?php echo Lang::get('Select Language'); ?>
                    <select id="language_dropdown" name="language_dropdown">
                        <option value="en">English</option>
                        <option value="de">German</option>
                        <option value="fr">French</option>
                    </select>
```

jquery to cal controller to save language code is:-

```
$(function() {
                    $('#language_dropdown').change(function() {
                    alert($(this).val());
                    var  val = $(this).val(); 
                                              $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:  "<?php echo Uri::base(false) ?>language",
                        data: { 'val' : val },
                        success: function(response){
                            location.reload();
                          },
                           error: function(response){
                           alert("There is some problem, please try again later");
                           }

                          }); 
                    });
                });
```

Controller to save session value:-

```
public function action_index()
  {
     $val = $_POST['val'];
     Session::set('lang', $val);
  }
```

Now I have to set language and load language file named language.php in every template files.

```
Config::set('language', Session::get('lang'));
Lang::load('language');
```

Is there is any way to set language and load language file globally so that there is no need to write above two lines in every file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load language file and config setting in controller. Basically there is a function before() which is loaded before any other function is called. you can load it in this function like

```
 public function before()
   {
      if(!Session::get('lang')){
             Session::set('lang', 'en');
        }
              Config::set('language', Session::get('lang'));
              Lang::load('lang');
     }
```

So you will get language file and config settings in all templates.